# Parsing a particular log using regex?

Tags: regex

The log example is

```
DHCPRELEASE of 123.4.5.89 from 12:34:45:56:78:90 (Johns-Iphone) via eth1 relay 1.3.4.4
```

where `123.4.5.89` is ip address, `12:34:45:56:78:90`is mac address, `Johns-Iphone` is Host.

Case 1 - I want this to have **no** matching group (missing left parenthesis)

```
DHCPRELEASE of 123.4.5.89 from 12:34:45:56:78:90 Johns-Iphone) via eth1 relay 1.3.4.4
```

Case 2 - This can be parsed

```
DHCPRELEASE of 123.4.5.89 from 12:34:45:56:78:90 (Johns-Iphone) via eth1 relay 1.3.4.4
```

Case 3 - This can be parsed as well

```
DHCPRELEASE of 123.4.5.89 from 12:34:45:56:78:90 via eth1 relay 1.3.4.4
```

Case 4 - This can be parsed as well

```
DHCPRELEASE of 123.4.5.89 from 12:34:45:56:78:90
```

**Here is my regex to parse this particular log:**

```
DHCPRELEASE\sof\s((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}(?:[0-9]{1,3}))\sfrom\s((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2})(?:\s\((.*?)\))?
```

However my regex does **NOT** work what I want. Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @anubhava Case 1 does not work, it actually has matching group and can be parsed. I don't want that.

Comment: Do you want no match at all for case 1?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Yes, I want no match at all for case 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
DHCPRELEASE\sof\s((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}(?:[0-9]{1,3}))\sfrom\s((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2})(?:\s\(([^)]*)\))?(?=\svia|$)
```

i.e. have a lookahead `(?=\svia)` in the end in order to make sure unmatched `(...)` is not matched for case 1.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kP0eL8/3)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. What about Case 4 in my question (I just edited my question)? Is it possible? I want the parser to be very particular about what it recognizes.

Answer (score 0):

because `(?:\s\((.*?)\))?` is optional you don't force the parentheses to match.
it's only matching the substring

```
DHCPRELEASE of 123.4.5.89 from 12:34:45:56:78:90
```

and ignoring the rest.

You could append " via" to your regular expression to force the match until that point.

**EDIT**

to be more precise you could add start and end anchors to your regular expression so it matches the entire line.

for example

```
^DHCPRELEASE\sof\s((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}(?:[0-9]{1,3}))\sfrom\s((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2})(?:\s\((.*?)\))?( via eth1 relay.*)?$
```

will match the entire line or nothing. note "^" to match the beginning of the line, and "$" to match the end.

Comment: Thanks for your input 1010. I added case 4 to my question - Is is possible to have a regex fitting all my cases?